# drawerContentOptions not working in Menu Drawer in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

in my react-native application I'm rendering a menu drawer with some routes.

When this route is active, I would like to change the background color, improving the visual effect of the application. I am using `drawerContentOptions` to try to do this, but it is not working.

I put my whole code into [snack](https://snack.expo.io/_UeCt-axh)

[image]

**AppJs**

```js
<SafeAreaProvider>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer />
  </NavigationContainer>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

**Drawer Navigator**

```js
  <Drawer.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Start"
    drawerType="slide"
    overlayColor="transparent"
    contentOptions={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}
    drawerStyle={{ width: '45%', backgroundColor: '#1F1B33' }}
    contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
    drawerContentOptions={{
      activeBackgroundColor: 'red',
      activeTintColor: 'red',
    }}
    drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Navigator" component={Navigator} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
```

**DrawerContent**

```js
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <View>
        <DrawerItem
          label="Start"
          labelStyle={{ color: '#fff' }}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Start')}
        />
        <DrawerItem
          label="Your Cart"
          labelStyle={{ color: '#fff' }}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Cart')}
        />
        <DrawerItem
          label="Favorites"
          labelStyle={{ color: '#fff' }}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Favorites')}
        />
        <DrawerItem
          label="Your Orders"
          labelStyle={{ color: '#fff' }}
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Orders')}
        />
      </View>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
```

**Stack.Navigator**

```js
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTransparent: true,
        headerTitle: null,
        headerTitleAlign: 'left',
        headerLeft: () => (
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}>
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                marginTop: 60,
              }}>
              <Image
                source={require('../assets/images/menu.png')}
                style={{ height: 30, width: 30, margin: 30 }}
              />
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Favorites" component={Favorites} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={Orders} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={Start} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

Can you tell me how do I make this work?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your DrawerContent doesn't have a named function.
You can put the DrawerItemList icons as options from the Drawer Screen. Here's an example

```
const DrawerContent = props => {
  return (
  <View>
      <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
        <DrawerItemList {...props} />
      </DrawerContentScrollView>
 </View>
  );
};
export default DrawerContent
```